# how to convert string to color in unity c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, colors, typeconverter, rgba

I have converted a color in Unity c# to string

```
> Body_Color=carParts_colorParts[0].materials[0].GetColor("_MainColor").ToString();
```

Now the output value is

> RGBA(1.000, 0.000, 0.000, 1.000)

I want to convert back this RGBA() to color.

how can we do this

Comment: just save the color in var and get the text when needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way to convert a color to string and back would be using [ColorUtility.ToHtmlStringRGBA](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ColorUtility.ToHtmlStringRGBA.html) and [ColorUtility.TryParseHtmlString](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ColorUtility.TryParseHtmlString.html).

If you want to parse the ToString() result manually you could do it with something like this:

```
string Body_Color = "RGBA(1.000, 0.000, 0.000, 1.000)";
string[] rgba = Body_Color.Substring(5, Body_Color.Length - 6).Split(", ");
Color color = new Color(float.Parse(rgba[0]), float.Parse(rgba[1]), float.Parse(rgba[2]), float.Parse(rgba[3]));
```